# Oracle : Creating record-column history

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Usually the best solution to capture history would be to create a trigger which takes snapshot of the record while updating into a history table however :

1.) My table contains 60 columns but I want to capture history for only 10 of them.

2.) The data from source come's with a **Submit date** which is not captured in the target table. The history need's to be captured based on that **Submit date** sent by the source and not based on current sysdate.

3.) We have control over the Select, Update process.

**Proposed Solution:**

We created a function as below

```
In(Primary Key, Submit_Date, Column_Name, Old Value, New Value)
PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;

Fetch max(Submit_date) From History using PK;

If max_Submit_date is Null: 
    Insert in History using PK, 01-01-1700 as Submit date, Column Name, Old_Value;
    Insert into History using PK & Submit_date & new Value;
Elsif max_Submit_date = Submit_date
    Update History using PK & Submit_date with new Value;
Elsif max_Submit_date < Submit_date
    Insert into History using PK & Submit_date & new Value;
End if;

commit;
```

While selecting data for update we added

```
select .... , 
DECODE(T.Column_VALUE_1,S.Column_VALUE_1,NULL,Function(PK,'COLUMN_NAME_1', S.Submit_Date, T.Column_VALUE_1, S.Column_VALUE_1)) XYZ,
DECODE(T.Column_VALUE_2,S.Column_VALUE_2,NULL,Function(PK,'COLUMN_NAME_2', S.Submit_Date, T.Column_VALUE_2, S.Column_VALUE_2)) XYZ,
From Source_Table S Join Target Table T Where ...
```

I can see that the solution is not ideal or efficient. Please advise if the requirement can be met in any other way.

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to perform it for all records, at once, utilizing a `MERGE INTO` statement. Since your submit_date is part of `insert` and also comparison, ideal solution to avoid conflict would be to have a `version` column in your `History` table, containing 1 for initial version and 2,3,4.. and so on for subsequent versions.

And instead of comparing with decode and calling function, you could exclude all such records in where clause condition.

```
MERGE INTO HISTORY h USING 
(

with m(pk,max_Submit_date) AS 
  ( select pk,submit_date,version 
           FROM HISTORY o where 
        version IN ( select MAX(version) max_version
                                     FROM HISTORY i where i.pk = o.pk ) ,

select .... PK, 
CASE WHEN m.max_Submit_date is Null 
 THEN 01-01-1700 
  WHEN  m.max_Submit_date <= s.Submit_date THEN 
s.Submit_date
END as Submit_date,
decode( m.max_Submit_date,NULL,T.Column_VALUE_1, S.Column_VALUE_1)
decode( m.max_Submit_date,NULL,T.Column_VALUE_2, S.Column_VALUE_2)
..
CASE WHEN m.max_Submit_date is Null
 THEN 1
   WHEN  m.max_Submit_date <= s.Submit_date
     THEN m.max_version + 1 new_version
    ELSE 
 m.max_version
END version 

From Source_Table S Join Target Table T 
JOIN m ON m.pk = s.pk 
Where ..

( T.Column_VALUE_1 != S.Column_VALUE_1 ) OR
( T.Column_VALUE_2 != S.Column_VALUE_2 ) OR
..
..


) cur

ON ( cur.pk = h.pk and h.version = cur.version )

WHEN MATCHED THEN 
Update SET h.Submit_date = cur.Submit_date,
h.Column_VALUE_1 = s.Column_VALUE_1,
h.Column_VALUE_2 = s.Column_VALUE_2
..


WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT

INSERT (PK,submit_date,column_1,..) VALUES (..);
```

Comment: Basically in this solution we have a history table identical to the normal table (hope i interpret it properly) however in my case the history table capture's COLUMN_NAME, NEW VALUE, OLD VALUE separately for each column.

Comment: @pOrinG : That is a poor design for history table. Ideally It should be identical to base table and have multiple versions. Just keeping one new value and and one old value doesn't count as history. It is something like a "reset" table. So, a better design should be to have a History table as suggested in the solution.

Comment: As stated in the question, `1.) My table contains 60 columns but I want to capture history for only 10 of them.` All my history requirement's are like that and we don't want to create unnecessary storage requirements. Also there are some column's (like 1-2) which change often but rest of them get updated rarely. It doesn't make sense to create a replica of base table in this case which just eats up the space.

Comment: @pOring : Then why not create history table with only those 10 columns?

Comment: As I said, Also there are some column's (like 1-2) which change often but rest of them get updated rarely.